# how to check divisibility of a very long number in c++?

Tags: c++, long-integer, modulo, factorization

How to check divisibility of a very long number in c++?
i have to check if **(3*n*n+3*n-1)** **is divisible by 2 , 3 and 5** and **n can be upto 10^10** so **long long int** is also **doubtful** to work although i have tried doing this:

```
unsigned long long int gg4,l;
gg4=(3*n*n+3*n-1);
if(gg4%3==0){
    gg4=gg4/3;
}
if(gg4%2==0){
    gg4=gg4/2;
}
if(gg4%5==0){
    gg4=gg4/2;
}
```

But i guess this wont work because of the range of n so please help! :)

after this i also need to **divide** **(3*n*n+3*n-1)** by that factor so please help!

Comment: It will never be divisible by 2, because either `3*n*n` is odd or `3*n-1` is odd. It'll never be divisible by 3 either. That only leaves 5.

Comment: is `if(gg4%`  **`5`** `==0)gg4=gg4/` **`2`** mistype?

Comment: Range is a problem. 10^10 takes ~33 bits, so n*n takes ~66 bits.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, there are two cases when `(3*n*n+3*n-1) % 5 == 0`, namely

- `n = 5 * m + 1`
- `n = 5 * m + 3`

For `m` an integer.

So in fact you don't need to calculate a long anything, you can work directly with `n`, and never even calculate `3 * n * n + 3 * n - 1` in the first place.

Just check:

```
n % 5 == 1 || n % 5 == 3
```

Comment: So the homework as set was a misdirection? Who would have thought it.

Comment: So just check that the last digit is `1`, `3`, `6` or `8`.